# Why proving that two languages used to merge into a regular language are not necessarily regular isn't possible with closure properties?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

> Let $L$ be a regular language over alphabet $\Sigma$. $L$ is the result of merging $2$ languages letter by letter that is for $a_1a_2...a_n\in L_1, b_1b_2...b_n\in L_2, L=a_1b_1a_2b_2...a_nb_n$. $\epsilon \in L \iff\epsilon \in L_1,L_2$. Does this mean that $L_1$ is necessarily regular?

At first I tried to prove that this is true using closure properties of regular languages before finding out that the claim is not true (e.g. $L_1=\{a^ib^i|i\ge 0\}, L_2=\{ab\}$).

I'd like to understand though what's wrong with my proof:

1) Define homomorphism $h:\Sigma\to \Sigma^*\cup \Sigma'^*$ as follows: $h(\sigma)=h(\sigma')=\sigma$ for $\sigma,\sigma'\in \Sigma.$

2) Let $X=h^{-1}(L)\cap(\Sigma\Sigma^*)$

3) Define another homomorphism: $f_1:\Sigma^*\cup \Sigma'^*\to \Sigma$ like this: 
$$
f_1(\sigma)=\sigma\\f_1(\sigma')=\epsilon
$$
4) Define another homomorphism: $f_2:\Sigma^*\cup \Sigma'^*\to \Sigma$ like this: 
$$
f_2(\sigma')=\sigma'\\f_2(\sigma)=\epsilon
$$
Then $L_1=f_1(X), L_2=f_2(X)$. Now if either $L_1$ or $L_2$ is not regular than it's contradiction because by closure properties they should've been regular. Where is my mistake?

---

**EDIT:** following one of the comments, the problem with the attempt to use closure properties is that apply the homomorphisms $f_1,f_2$ on $X$ we may get a different language from the original one.

Comment: You have a counterexample in your question. What do you learn when you apply this counterexample in the construction of your suggested proof?

Comment: Now I see, if I apply my construction I get a different language.

Comment: @Yos, write an answer?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I added an edit section in the OP, the answer seems to be so minimal that I don't think it warrants an answer. Let me know if the rules encourage adding an official answer in such situations.

Comment: There is no binding rules but there are some factors to consider. The problem with a question without an (accepted) answer is that it will be treated by the site vastly different from questions  with an (accepted) answer. It will be tallied and listed differently. It will attract the wrong kinds of attention. If you think this question will not be helpful for any future reader, you may delete the question (which is rarely done when there is an answer). In general, I will encourage askers to write answers since they know best about what has been the difficulty.

Comment: For this kind of exercises it is often useful to check for trivial cases, first. E.g. one might assume the conjecture, choose (say) $L_1$ to be the empty (or full) language, and simplify the statement accordingly. Sometimes, a counterexample can now be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction outputs the language
$$ \{ w \in L_1 : \exists z \in L_2 \text{ s.t. } |z|=|w| \}. $$
In words, it outputs those words in $L_1$ whose length matches the length of some word in $L_2$. In general, this could be much smaller than $L_1$.

In particular, if $L_2$ is a finite language, then the result of merging $L_1$ and $L_2$ is finite, and so regular, for *every* language $L_1$.